# Display photo vertically aligned

Tags: html, css

I tried to display dynamic photos(from backend file) and loop it.So far I am able to display it vertically using css

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

But once I added a photo name for each image, the position got messed up

[image]

```
  with <span class="span_pics">project.name</span>
```

[image]

```
   without <span class="span_pics">project.name</span>
```

Html

```
 <img src="http://localhost:8082/uploads/documents/default-project.jpg" id="img-responsive">
 <span class="span_pics">project.name</span>
```

css

```
   img#img-responsive{
        height: 225px;
        width: 225px;
        vertical-align: middle;

   }
   .span_pics{
        margin: 2px;
   }
```

How to add a centered text below the image without affecting its current position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap everything in a div and then align the picture and the title as you please. I have put together a sample for you to look at:

https://jsfiddle.net/max234435/ua3cy4h6/1/

I created a `<div class='picture'></div>` and put the rest of your code in there as you will see.

I hope thats what you are looking for unless i'm misunderstanding your question.